# react-spring: execute callback after 1st rest only

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, react-spring

I have the following looping `spring`

```
  const [swipeSpring, _] = useSpring(() => {
    return {
      from: { backgroundPosition: '0 0' },
      to: { backgroundPosition: reducedMotion ? '0 0' : '115% 0' },
      config: { duration: 2000 },
      delay: 500,
      loop: true,
      onRest: ...  // <-------
    };
  }, [reducedMotion]);
```

I want to execute a function on the *initial* `rest`, not each subsequent loop's rest.  Does `react-spring` provide a mechanism to do this?  I'm not seeing that level of specificity in the [react-spring Events docs](https://www.react-spring.dev/docs/advanced/events).

I *could* just fudge it with some `setTimeout`s because I control all the timing from within the component, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this specific use case.